# How to run a maven plugin without a POM in Jenkins?

Tags: maven, jenkins

I have a plugin which can run either using a `pom.xml` or without (depends upon the version of the artifact we're building: new versions go without a pom. Strange, I know).

I want to have that plugin run in Jenkins.
But when creating a maven project, I have to set a pom (or as a default, Jenkins suppose there is one in the base folder given).

**Question**: Is it possible to configure Jenkins to not use a pom when there is none?

Comment: a free style build with an execute shell/Windows build step?

Comment: which triggers other issues on that machine ...

Comment: What kind of issues? A free style build is the way to go when you don't have a `pom.xml` (btw sometimes even when you have one).

Comment: @JoaoMorais See [Maven goals run in Java6 mode when run in a Jenkins freestyle job](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35336061/15619)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my comment, you should use a Jenkins freestyle project build in this case, in order to have more flexibility and avoid the default assumptions of a Jenkins Maven build.

In such a build, you can then configure a build step executing a shell or a Windows command (depending on the Jenkins server OS).

Indeed, in the Jenkins Maven build, a pom file is always required, as mentioned in the help support of the Configuration > Build > Root Pom entry

> If your workspace has the top-level pom.xml in somewhere other than the 1st module's root directory, specify the path (relative to the module root) here, such as parent/pom.xml. 
>   If left empty, defaults to pom.xml