# Maven goals run in Java6 mode when run in a Jenkins freestyle job

Tags: maven, jenkins

On my jenkins machine, as far as I know, I have two Java installations :

```
[1041][root@server:/tmp]$ alternatives --display java
java - status is manual.
 link currently points to /logiciels/jdk/jdk1.7.0_76_Linux_64bits/jre/bin/java
/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.6.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/java - priority 16000
```

I have configured only the jdk 7 to be usable in my jobs.
But, when I run my freestyle job containing a maven goal, I always get

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: myPlugin : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:637)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClassFromSelf(ClassRealm.java:386)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:244)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:230)
    at org.sonatype.guice.bean.reflect.URLClassSpace.loadClass(URLClassSpace.java:101)
```

which seems to indicate that my plugin runs on a java 6 JRE. How ? And how can I change that ?

**UPDATE**

I've taken the liberty to run the maven executable from command line ... with the following result.

```
[1041][root@server:/tmp]$ /logiciels/apache-maven-3.0.5/bin/mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.0.5 (r01de14724cdef164cd33c7c8c2fe155faf9602da; 2013-02-19 14:51:28+0100)
Maven home: /logiciels/apache-maven-3.0.5
Java version: 1.6.0_65, vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
Java home: /logiciels/jdk/jdk1.6.0_65_Linux_64bits/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "2.6.32-358.11.1.el6.x86_64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

So, it seems the "run maven high level goals" just triggers that mvn executable, which uses an incorrectly configured java version. But weird can only get weirder :

```
[1041][root@server:/tmp]$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/logiciels/jdk/jdk1.5.0_51_Linux_64bits/jre
```

Comment: on the freestyle jenkins build, configuration, at the top, before the Advanced Project Options, you can set the JDK used, is that at the correct value?

Comment: @A.DiMatteo please transform you comment into an answer I can (and will) accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the Jenkins freestyle project configuration, you can check the JDK settings applied to the build, at the top of the configuration page, before the "Advanced Project Options" section. Below a picture pointing at the concerned configuration entry

[image]

Be sure you are using the JDK of interest. The values available from the drop down box are the JDK configured via Jenkins > Manage Jenkins > Configure System > JDK > JDK Installations..

I just created a free-style build with two steps running a `javac -version` and a `mvn -version` and changing JDK version in two runs and indeed changes are effectively applied as expected.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to set jdk used by maven plugins is by [using maven toolchains](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-using-toolchains.html).

Fisrt, create a `toolchains.xml` in your `.m2` directory containing something like:

```
<toolchains xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/TOOLCHAINS/1.1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/TOOLCHAINS/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/toolchains-1.1.0.xsd">
    <toolchain>
        <type>jdk</type>
        <provides>
            <version>1.7</version>
        </provides>
        <configuration>
            <jdkHome>/path/to/your/jdk7</jdkHome>
        </configuration>
    </toolchain>
</toolchains>
```

You can have several toolchain defined in this file, each providing a specific version of java and his path.

Then, add the toolchain plugin in your pom:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-toolchains-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>toolchain</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <toolchains>
            <jdk>
                <version>1.7</version>
            </jdk>
        </toolchains>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Once you do that, many plugins, including compiler maven plugin, will use the jdk selected by the toolchain configuration.

Doing that let you use any version of java to execute maven or the jdk set on main path, and add abstraction on where find java on specific machine because defined in toolchains.xml configuration.

BTW, you should consider upgrading maven to [version 3.3+](https://maven.apache.org/docs/history.html) because you use a old (deprecated?) version (3.0)

Comment: note that this question is a follow up of [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35335871/how-to-run-a-maven-plugin-without-a-pom-in-jenkins), so there is no pom file involved

Comment: Yeah, for sure, I have a Jenkins problem, and you answer with modifications in not only my pom (which is easily shared between machines, although I have none here - but i didn't told so) *and* my settings.xml, which are not shared, so I should change them by hand on any machine involved. Not exactly the cleanest solution, I think ;-)

Comment: @Riduidel Toolchains configuration can be done directly on Jenkins for all agent since version 2.3 (2012), like other maven settings. https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Config+File+Provider+Plugin

Comment: btw, i didn't notice that you don't have pom file, which is surprising... :) So the usual correct way is to use maven toolchains configuration, but without pom i don't now if you can really